# jQuery conflict with Prototype (noconflict doesnt work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I use jQuery v1.6.4 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js
and [prototype](http://www.thegamelounge.net/public/js/3rd_party/prototype.js).

I am trying to use the jQuery Tabs widget and it conflicts with prototype. As a result the upload button of an input isn't working.

I tried this to resolve but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  _ccsjQ(function() {
    _ccsjQ( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

The funny thing is that if i press F5 the upload button works and when i refresh, doesnt work.

Comment: `var _cssjQ = jQuery.noConflict();` need to assign the alias.

Comment: Why are you using two largely overlapping libraries? That's just asking for trouble. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957575/jquery-conflict-with-sfwobject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way (IMHO) is just call `jQuery.noConflict()` then wrap any jQuery code in an anonymous function:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
  // use your standard $(...) in here
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, you need to assign jQuery a new alias if you're not going to use `jQuery(...)` (e.g. `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();` then use `jq(...)`).

Example of both being used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _cssjQ = jQuery.noConflict();
        _cssjQ('.foo').css('color','#f0f');
        (function($){
            $('.bar').css('color','#f0f');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbWah/1/

Answer (score 0):

1) Define Jquery first

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) Add script after Jquery and Before prototype

```
<script>
  var pjquery = jQuery.noConflict();//pjquery will represent jquery framework now on-wards
</script>
```

3) Now define prototype.js

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/prototype.js" ></script>
```

---

Now where ever jquery is to be called use `pjquery` instead of `$` or `Jquery`.