# jQuery conflict with sfwObject

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery to create Tabs
(www.jqueryui.com/tabs/). I use jQuery v1.6.4

In the same page there is a sfwobject for uploading files and it requires adobe flash player. The problem is that it conflicts with jQuery. I tried some noConflict methods, but didnt found a solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _cssjQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    _ccsjQ(function() {
       _ccsjQ( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Here are two files that have to do with the sfwobject.

http://www.thegamelounge.net/public/js/3rd_party/swfupload/swfupload.js
http://www.thegamelounge.net/public/js/3rd_party/swfupload/swfupload.sfw

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery no conflicts only works for conflicting '$'. Check for any public methods which have same name in your action script too.

Comment: not found any. also check this file: http://www.thegamelounge.net/public/js/ips.attach.js

http://gyazo.com/4e36547feb78503a2c39105e7dd476bf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery no conflict removes the $ alias, you will need to use this form if you plan to use the $ alias:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // code using $ as alias to jQuery
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  /// other stuff that uses the $ alias can go here
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // other code
     $(document).click(function(){
        alert("howdy");
     });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

That `ips.attach.js` uses the $ alias, you will need to wrap it in a no-conflict that passes the $ back in such as the example above - use care as this will potentially remove the functions inside there from the global namespace also.